# Bizarre grey screen appearing after main installer page in Ubuntu Bionic

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, netinstall

I'm seeing a bizarre grey screen appear right after the main installation page shows up in Ubuntu Bionic. I'm installing this on a VM and I duplicated the settings from an exact replica of the machine I'm installing onto that worked fine with no issues. This is coming off of the Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS NetInstaller "mini.iso". I see a mention about 'klogd' before this happens. Any ideas?

[image: Installer screen]

[image: Grey stalling screen]

Comment: What specific settings have you duplicated?

Comment: Disk, RAM, CPU, and GPU. Nothing else was touched from the defaults.